# C# ArrayList with C++ Interop

Tags: c#, c++, com, clr, com-interop

Got this in C#

```
public static ArrayList MyFct() 
{
  var x = new ArrayList();
  x.Add(5);
  return x
}
```

On C++ side with Interop, after calling Invoke_3(), I get a **variant_t** which contains my array, but how can I "extract" it ?

(for instance I would like to get the number of items, etc.)

Comment: Begs the question: why are you using `ArrayList` and not `List<int>`

Comment: Because I don't know how to expose generic with variant in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [VARIANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-variant) (`variant_t` is a wrapper that comes from `comdef.h` / `#import` statement) that contains an [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) reference, so you can use `IDispatch`'s methods, for example like this (error checks omitted):

```
variant_t v;
HRESULT hr = unk->GetList(&v); // get my VARIANT that contains an ArrayList reference

// get "Count" method dispid
LPOLESTR countName = (LPOLESTR)L"Count";
DISPID dispidCount;
hr = V_DISPATCH(&v)->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &countName, DISPATCH_METHOD, 0, &dispidCount);

DISPPARAMS dp = { nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0 };
variant_t count;
hr = V_DISPATCH(&v)->Invoke(dispidCount, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dp, &count, nullptr, nullptr);

// get "Item(i)" method dispid
LPOLESTR itemName = (LPOLESTR)L"Item";
DISPID dispidName;
hr = V_DISPATCH(&v)->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &itemName, DISPATCH_METHOD, 0, &dispidName);

for (int i = 0; i < V_I4(&count); i++)
{
    // build index as variant
    variant_t index(i);
    DISPPARAMS dpIndex = { &index, nullptr, 1, 0 };

    // get item(i)
    variant_t item;
    hr = V_DISPATCH(&v)->Invoke(dispidName, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dpIndex, &item, nullptr, nullptr);

    // item can be a scalar value
    // String => VT_BSTR, Int32 => VT_I4, etc.
    // or another ComVisible object => VT_DISPATCH, VT_UNKNOWN, etc.
}
```

Comment: Merci Simon, vous m'avez -encore- sauvé la vie !